# C#: Attach an in-memory iTextSharp pdf as an Outlook attachment

Tags: c#, pdf, outlook, itext

I'm attempting to attach an iTextSharp pdf to an Outlook MailItem, but actually adding the Attachment always results in an ArgumentException, with the additional information simply saying, "Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again."

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void SendPDF(string subject, string body, string To)
{
    var pdf = GeneratePDF();

    Outlook.Application mailApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mail = mailApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = subject;            
    mail.Body = body;            

    var addresses = To.Split(',');            

    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        mail.Recipients.Add(address);
    }

    //error happens here:
    mail.Attachments.Add(pdf, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, EquipmentName + ".pdf");
    mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();

    mail.Send();
}
```

Not attaching the pdf results in a successful email being sent, but obviously this defeats the point. Creating the pdf and storing it somewhere is not an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first argument of Attachments.Add is a *filename* (full path), passing it the content of a generated pdf will definitely result in an error.

Comment: @Paul-Jan Really? The hover text shows that the first argument is "object Source". Is that simply misleading?

Either way, thanks for your response! Do you know of a different way to do this?

Comment: It's either a filename or another MailItem you want to attach (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869553.aspx). There is no way to do this through the .NET Outlook Object Model... Either use Redemption (commercial product), reproduce what Redemption does (lot of work), or avoid Outlook completely and use MailMessage to send the email.

Comment: @Paul-Jan Thank you! I ended up switching over to using a MailMessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted by Paul-Jan in the comments, attaching an in-memory pdf is not possible with Outlook. I have switched to a MailMessage.